# Mysterious Data Connection shows up after running excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

Note: I know how to break links in macros.  I'm asking because I'm curious about what's happening, not how to work around it.

I have an excel Macro that exports data from timecards into a separate document.  It works fine, but I was trying to optimize it.  In doing so, I noticed there is apparently an external data connection linking to a table in a sheet in the original workbook that is isolated from the sheet I pull data from.  It does not appear in any data validation nor does it appear in any conditional formatting.  And yet, it appears as an external data source in the output workbook.

To make matters weirder, the output workbook is split into two sheets.  Deleting *either* sheet will delete the reference but clearing all in both will not.  So far, I have checked:

Data validation

Every formula

Every cell value

Conditional formatting

Name manager

And have used all search functions to try to find the table's name or even stuff like "*!".

I have no idea where this external data is hiding or what I can do about it.  Has anyone experienced something like this and how have you dealt with it (besides break link)?

Note:

The data table is a timezone table and is not referenced in the cells because the cells that pull data from it get pasted as values before being copied into the new worksheet.

Comment: and you are absolutely sure that you checked the name manager too? because most of the time these rogue connections hide in there

Comment: Links in data validation are sometimes the hardest to find. Did you check *all* cells with data validation? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-cells-that-have-data-validation-rules-7940468a-c95d-422f-a3fb-8fa0b90e5810